# What is this small creature on the bottom of this leaf?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology

[image: first image]
This first one appears to have been flattened by the slide cover.
[image: second image]
This one is not flattened.
Probably like .2/.3 mm in size. All of them seem dead because they are doing nothing. All on the underside of the leaf.

I found these on a leaf. I am in a forested area of South Carolina. Here is an image of the tree where these are.
[image: tree branch]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sessile, sap-sucking insect, most likely a [whitefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly) larva close to maturation. Like you say, they attach to the underside of leaves and don't move. Unlike some scale insects, to which whiteflies are related, these will eventually hatch into a more normal-looking fly. Here's an image of a whitefly larva for comparison:

[image: Late fourth instar whitefly larva]

The second image may be the abandoned skin after molting, these are usually more visible than live larva.
More photos showing more of the life-cycle and different species are available on [this University of Florida website](https://mrec.ifas.ufl.edu/lso/Whitelfies.htm).

Comment: I had scale insect in my mind, but lack of evidence to suggest so.